# How could I pass a Generic List from Client to Server in WCF?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, list, generics, serialization

I query data with NHibernate in the server side, then I create a WCF service which is the one that publishes these NHibernate objects, they are correctly serialized to Silverlight, I modify them in my application but when I send them back to the server they get serlialized again, and Generic Lists get converted to Array so I cannot modify them anymore in the server side...

this is my class definition

```
public class BIMenu
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual String DisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual String ProgramToCall { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<BIMenu> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<BISecurityProfile> SecurityProfiles { get; set; }
    public virtual Boolean IsApplication
    {
        get
        {
            if (Children.Count < 1 && ProgramToCall != null)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
    public virtual Boolean IsFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return !IsApplication;
        }
    }

    public BIMenu()
    {
        Children = new List<BIMenu>();
        SecurityProfiles = new List<BISecurityProfile>();
    }
}
```

and this is my contract

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface IBISecurityService
{
    [OperationContract]
    BIMenu GetMenu(String Name);

    [OperationContract]
    void SaveMenu(BIOnline.Model.BIMenu Menu);

    [OperationContract]
    void DeleteMenu(BIOnline.Model.BIMenu Menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your `BIMenu` class marked `[DataContract]`? I would expect it to be:

```
[DataContract]
public class BIMenu
{
  [DataMember]
  public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public virtual String DisplayName { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public virtual String ProgramToCall { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public virtual IList<BIMenu> Children { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public virtual IList<BISecurityProfile> SecurityProfiles { get; set; }
```

Also, if your `IList<BIMenu> Children` and `IList<BISecurityProfile> SecurityProfiles` properties are being set to instances of the `Array` type, then that is perfectly valid, since `Array` implements `IList`.  If you want to keep them as actual `List<>` instances, then just define the properties as `List<>` instead of `IList<>`, like this:

```
// Defined as actual Lists, not IList interfaces.
[DataMember]
public virtual List<BIMenu> Children { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public virtual List<BISecurityProfile> SecurityProfiles { get; set; }
```